# Finding Lat/Long using polygon or circle as search

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding, geospatial

I'm out of my element here so please forgive me if I dont ask this correctly/clearly.

I have a table of users with lat/long for each one.

I get a query from a federal agency that provides either a polygon or a circle like this:

```
<polygon>38.47,-120.14 38.34,-119.95 38.52,-119.74 38.62,-119.89 38.47,-120.14</polygon>
<circle>32.9525,-115.5527 0</circle>
```

Given either of these two inputs, I need to return all users within the polygon or circle.

I've looked all over, read all the mysql spatial docs etc. and I am either missing a step or just not grokking the query method.

ANY help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that `0` in the `<circle>` the radius? If so, then you'll have zero people inside that circle, unless they're ultra-anorexic.

Comment: For Circles, I hope it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586708/get-results-that-fall-within-marker-radiuses-from-database/

Answer (score 0):

Have you read http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/ ?

Comment: Believe it or not, that's the ONE blog I hadn't found!  It's now safely bookmarked.

Answer (score 0):

For a circle, you would need to compute the distance from the circle center to each of the lat/lon's in your persons list.  If the distance is less than the radius of the circle, that person is inside the circle.  Typical formula for computing distances between 2 lat/lon's along the 'great circle' is called the haversine formula.  The website below shows this formula in javascript.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

<strike>For a general polygon, this is much harder.</strike>
For general point in a polygon, the [Point Inclusion Test](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) seems to work assuming a trivial Equirectanglular projection (x = lon, y = lat).

Comment: Thanks Trey.. I'm already using the haversine to pull all users with 'x' miles of a starting lat/long... it's really a problem of dealing with the polygon/circle as spatial shapes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I came up with and appears to be working:

First, I altered the table by adding a field to hold the spatial points created from the users lat/lon:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD location POINT NOT NULL;
UPDATE users set location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ',lon,')'))
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX location ON users(location);
```

From there, I'm using this to query to find the users within the polygon:

```
SET @bbox = 'POLYGON((38.47,-120.14 38.34,-119.95 38.52,-119.74 38.62,-119.89 38.47,-120.14))';
SELECT * , AsText( location ) 
FROM users
WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText( @bbox ) ) ;
```

For new users I created a trigger to update the `location` from the lat/lon (user can't be added without a lat\lon):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `users_insert_defaults`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `users_insert_defaults` BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',NEW.lat,' ',NEW.lon,')'))
//
DELIMITER ;
```